# google tree control onClick

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to click a rectangle in the Google tree control and set a value in another part of the page.

I am using the following code, but nothing is happening as an alert.

```
    tree.draw(data, {
        minColor: '#f00',
        midColor: '#ddd',
        maxColor: '#0d0',
        headerHeight: 15,
        fontColor: 'black',
        showScale: true
    });
}


// this code does not work

function myOnClickFunction(){
    TreeMap.getSelection();
    var txt = TreeMap.getValue(0, TreeMap.getSelection());

    alert(txt);

}
google.visualization.events.addListener(TreeMap, 'select', myOnClickFunction);
// end of none working code
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 900px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you named the variable for your TreeMap visualization `tree` in your drawing function, but try to create an event handler using a variable called `TreeMap`.  Ssecond, your event handler is not in scope for your `tree` variable.  Third, the `getSelection` method does not return a column index by itself, so you can't use the output directly in the `getValue` method call.  Change the variable name and move the event handler inside your drawing function, and adjust the code inside the event handler like this:

```
function myOnClickFunction(){
    var selection = tree.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        var txt = data.getValue(selection[0].row, selection[0].column);
        alert(txt);
    }
}
google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', myOnClickFunction);
```